# What to use instead of LEFT REMOTE JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I have two linked SQL Servers (2008R2). The remote server contains a table with a huge number of rows. It has to be joined with a local table. In such a situation a good solution is using a [`REMOTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx) hint for `JOIN`.

But there is a restriction for using `REMOTE JOIN`:

> REMOTE can be used only for INNER JOIN operations.

I want to make a left join operation, but it will be done on the local side and whole HugeRemoteTable will be loaded on the local server:

```
SELECT HugeRemoteTable.*
FROM HugeRemoteTable
LEFT JOIN LocalTable 
    ON HugeRemoteTable.col = LocalTable.id
WHERE LocalTable.id IS NULL
```

Is it possible to rewrite query to join tables on the remote side and load only filtered data?

**EDIT1:**

I experimented wtih queries and it looks like SQL Server runs query remotely if condition is `LocalTable.id IS NULL`. The query takes a few time.

But a query with condition `LocalTable.id IS NOT NULL` takes much more time and obviously runs locally.

The same behavior demonstrate queries with `JOIN` rewrited as `NOT IN` or `IN` (they even have execution plans similar to plans for queries with JOIN).

This query runs very quickly:

```
SELECT *
FROM HugeRemoteTable
WHERE col NOT IN (SELECT id FROM LocalTable)
```

And this one takes a lot of time and generates a lot of requests to remote server (I don't know exactly why, but it looks like local server makes a request per each row from LocalTable):

```
SELECT *
FROM HugeRemoteTable
WHERE col IN (SELECT id FROM LocalTable)
```

Now we are going to `OPENQUERY`. I've connected my local server as linked server for remote SQL Server (in opposite direction) using alias 'localServer' and started with `OPENQUERY` in such a way

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(remote,'
    SELECT * FROM HugeRemoteTable
    LEFT JOIN localServer.localTable ON HugeRemoteTable.col=localTable.id 
    WHERE localTable.id is not null')
```

it was as fast as query with condition `LocalTable.id IS NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(remote,'
    SELECT * FROM HugeRemoteTable
    LEFT JOIN localServer.localTable ON HugeRemoteTable.col=localTable.id 
    WHERE localTable.id is null')
```

Both queries with OPENQUERY were very fast, but they need two-way linking between servers.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Maybe with a WHERE IN (subquery)?

Comment: @TabAlleman _not_ in - maybe select * from HugeRemoteTable where HugeRemoteTable.col not in ( select Id from LocalTable )

Comment: Ah, I didn't really read his query, I just saw LEFT JOIN, and thought "WHERE IN".   I didn't see that he wanted to use it to exclude the matches in the local table.   Good catch.

Comment: Tab, Clay thank you. I tryed the queries you've proposed and updated the question with my results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for speed and using linked servers, give this a try.

Step 1). Create a temp table with the data you need.
Step 2). Using Openquery is the way you want to go if you want speed. Create a temp table with the data you want from the other server. Using openquery and dynamic sql grab the data you want filtered. 
Step3). Use the temp table to join this.

```
 DECLARE @FlatTSQL varchar(8000)
DECLARE @AsOfDate date = '9/24/2015'

CREATE TABLE #MyData
(AsOfDate date)


SELECT  @FlatTSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(EUC,''
                                               SELECT 
                                                cal.AsOfDate
                                                FROM RiskReporting.Reference.lkpCalendar cal WITH(NOLOCK)
                                                WHERE CONVERT(date,cal.AsOfDate) = ''''' + CONVERT(varchar(25),@AsOfDate) + ''''''')'


INSERT INTO #MyData
EXEC (@FlatTSQL)

SELECT
*
FROM #MyData md

DROP TABLE #MyData
```

Let me know if it works, Alex

Comment: It is difficult to access my localTable from OPENQUERY. I need to select all ids into comma-separated string and then use it in dynamic query or connect my local SQL Server as linked server for remote one.

Answer (score 0):

OPENQUERY can be used to move the heavy execution to the appropriate server and the results can be brought back.

Your left join wouldn't filter rows by itself so you must specify a where clause or other join type in your remote query (EDIT: unless you specify your small table on the left side to match rows in large table when they exist).

[OPENQUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188427.aspx)